# Hibernate runtime exception SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hibernate gives me a run time error to the following query.It's saying that there is a syntax error.

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 1, column 16.
```

Note that transaction handling handled at the service layer that's why session related lines are not in the code.

```
 String hql = "UPDATE Lecturer L set L.id=:id,L.name=:name,L.department=:department,L.center=:center,L.facultyType=:facultyType,L.rank=:rank,L.level=:level,L.building.id=:buildingId,L.building.building=:building where L.id=:prevId";

        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("id", lecturerDTO.getId());
        query.setParameter("name", lecturerDTO.getName());
        query.setParameter("department", lecturerDTO.getDepartment());
        query.setParameter("center", lecturerDTO.getCenter());

        query.setParameter("facultyType", lecturerDTO.getFacultyType());
        query.setParameter("rank", lecturerDTO.getRank());
        query.setParameter("level", lecturerDTO.getLevel());
        query.setParameter("buildingId", lecturerDTO.getBuildingDTO().getId());
        query.setParameter("building", lecturerDTO.getBuildingDTO().getBuilding());
        query.setParameter("prevId", prevId);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Could you please provide code of your `Lecturer` entity. And by the way, why you just not update the entity `Lecturer`, at the end of transaction (at flushing time) hibernate will do this update for you.

Comment: @SternK can you please share the code for that with me because since id is a primary key in the lecturer entity hibernate didn't allow me to update when I set the values through setters for the relevant object by taking the object to persistence stage.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need to update primary key at all. It looks quite strange.